# Why do we use perturbative series if they don't converge?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, perturbation-theory, asymptotics

My course instructor mentioned that the Perturbative Series are not convergent but diverge as we consider more and more terms in the expansion. He then briefly mentioned that the Perturbative Series are [Asymptotic Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion). I have some idea about Asymptotic series, such as Stirling's approximation $\left (n!\sim {\sqrt {2\pi n}}\left({\frac {n}{e}}\right)^{n} \right )$, which gets better as $n$ increases.

**So, does it mean that the perturbative expansion of $n^{th}$ state energy ($E_n$) is gets better as $n$ increases?**

Comment: Pragmatically, you're going to feel the impact of unknown physics, ignored physics (gravity, say, in a typical LHC analysis) or imprecise inputs (after all we do experiments to increase precision) before you're going to feel the impact of the non-convergence of the perturbation series.

Comment: You may find these [lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.2714) useful.

Comment: I disagree. Lack of convergence is precisely why confinement is beyond the reach of perturbation theory. And, compared to gravity, this puts much harsher limitations on our ability to compare LHC results to theory.

Comment: @Connor Behan: On the other hand, what would it take to then do things the other way around, which is to say, could one try to _use_ the LHC data in that realm to try and help craft theory that goes beyond perturbative theories, which are indeed so limited? After all, that's how science works or should work ideally: data leads you to craft theory, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks @Oбжорoв

Comment: Well "perturbation theory" is a calculational technique rather than a theory. But it would be interesting if someone developed an improved technique that was heavily informed by data :).

Comment: I haven't looked at them but you might find these lecture series by Prof. Carl Bender useful. https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOFVFbzrQ49TNlDOxxCAjC7kbnorAR1MU

Comment: This book by Bender and Orszag might be useful as well. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-3069-2

Comment: Perturbation series that don't converge are simply a sign that we are using the wrong base functions to describe physics. A famous example of that is the Gibbs phenomenon: a Fourier series approximating a square function converges in an L_2 norm but not in an L_infinity norm (i.e. the largest pointwise error never converges towards zero). One can approximate square waves with a different orthogonal system than sines and cosines just fine, even in L_infinity.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The difference between a convergent and asymptotic series comes from reversing the order of two quantifiers.

- **Convergent**: For every $x$, there exists a large enough number of terms such that the error is less than $\epsilon$.
- **Asymptotic**: For every number of terms, there exists a small enough $x$ such that the error is less than $\epsilon$.

The utility of the latter can be summed up by [Carrier's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_F._Carrier#Carrier%27s_Rule): "Divergent series converge faster than convergent series because they don't have to converge". In other words, the approximation will get better for awhile and then start to get worse at a point that depends on $x$.

In the case of Stirling's approximation, the small number $x$ would be $1/n$. For perturbation theory in quantum mechanics though, it is some coefficient of an interaction Hamiltonian. I'm not aware of any result stating that in systems with a discrete spectrum, excited state energies are more easily approximated than the ground state energy. The [eigenstate thermalization hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenstate_thermalization_hypothesis) more or less tells us to expect the opposite.

Comment: And in QFT the analogue of $x$ is the energy?

Comment: It can be in effective field theory. But the most standard case would be $x = \alpha \approx 1/137$ analogously to QM.

Comment: you mean for every epsilon, there exists a large enough number of terms such that the error is less than epsilon? and for every number of terms, there exists a small enough epsilon?

Comment: Convergent: For every epsilon and x, there exists a large enough number of terms such that the error at x is less than epsilon.

Comment: Asymptotic: For every epsilon and number of terms, there exists a small enough x such that the error at x is less than epsilon.

Comment: It might be useful to add that in some cases like the $\phi^4$ model in 2 and 3 spacetime dimensions, the perturbative series diverges but is Borel summable. Essentially, given an analytic function $f(z)$ on a domain $\Omega$ one can associate to it an asymptotic series at any $z_0$ of the closure of the domain. The question is how to recover the function from the asymptotic series. If the point is in the interior then one uses ordinary summation and the classical notion of convergence is useful. If the point is on the boundary, one needs something like Borel summation...

Comment: ...and asking for convergence in the classical sense is not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just because I don't think there's a clear enough answer to your proposal that $n$ might be the energy level (as in $E_n$). No that's the wrong parameter to be increasing to get better precision. The equivalent to the $n$ in the Stirling approximation is the number of terms in the perturbative expansion. I.e. first order energy perturbation ($n=1$), second order ($n=2$), etc. Although most people don't go beyond second order energy perturbation in QM anyway because even if it was convergent the terms get complicated and difficult to compute.

So if you're using $n$'th order perturbation theory to compute the perturbed energy levels of a system, as you increase $n$, at some point the terms will start getting bigger rather than smaller, and you'll know that your answer is getting less, not more precise.

As was discussed in the other answer, the optimal choice for $n$ will depend on how big your perturbation is. Roughly speaking, I'd guess you can use first order perturbation theory to see how big the perturbations are, then the nominal energy level differences over the size of the perturbation is the order of magnitude of the optimal $n$.